# Cannot format nested date field in keystone.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, momentjs, swig-template, keystonejs

I am extending keystone.js to support multiple languages in the models.

The original model looks like this:

```
Post.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    publishedDate: { type: Types.Date, index: true },
    //... more irrelevant fields
});
```

My extended model looks like this:

```
Post.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    en: {
        title: { type: String },
        publishedDate: { type: Types.Date, index: true },
        //... more irrelevant fields
    },
    es: {
        title: { type: String },
        publishedDate: { type: Types.Date, index: true },
        //... more irrelevant fields
    },
    //... more languages following the same pattern
});
```

I am having an issue using the nested publishedDate properties within the view templates.

Original view code that works with the original model:

```
{% if post.publishedDate %}
    <br>on {{ post._.publishedDate.format('MMMM DD, YYYY') }}
{% endif %}
```

Adjusted view code for my new model (this is where I am having the issue):

```
{% if post[lang].publishedDate %}
    <br>on {{ post[lang]._.publishedDate.format('MMMM DD, YYYY') }}
{% endif %}
```

Using `post[lang].xxxxxx` I can refer to all of the other items in my post (for example `post[lang].title`.

Am I missing something that is causing these nested underscore functions to fail with the following error?

> non_object_property_load Error thrown for request" /en/blog  
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'publishedDate' of undefined

**EDIT:**
It gets more peculiar... below seems to work:

```
{% if post[lang].publishedDate %}
    <br>on {{ post._[lang].publishedDate.format('MMMM DD, YYYY') }}
{% endif %}
```

If anyone can offer up an explanation of why this works (or a better way to accomplish this), I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JRulle, I assume the error is on the following line:

```
<br>on {{ post[lang]._.publishedDate.format('MMMM DD, YYYY') }}
```

The issue is that the underscore methods belong to the `List` object. For example, to access the underscore methods for `post.en.publishedDate` you would use the following syntax: `post._.en.publishedDate.format('MMMM DD, YYYY')`

You should change the above line to:

```
<br>on {{ post._[lang].publishedDate.format('MMMM DD, YYYY') }}
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you for the explanation as this was driving me nuts.